# Detecting if an object exists in IE

Tags: javascript

Normally if you want to check if a feature is supported in a browser, you'd do a simple if statement like this:

```
if (SomeFooFeature) { ... }
```

So in my application, I check for the AudioContext object, to avoid errors when trying to use it if it is not supported:

```
if (AudioContext) {
    context = new AudioContext()
}
```

But when I do that, IE complains that "AudioContext" is undefined.
**Uhm, what?** Didn't I just check for that?

Infact, just doing `if (Foo) { ... }` gives the same error.

Why? How can something this trivial not work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: try ```typeof AudioContext != 'undefined'```

Comment: Accept the one from @SantiagoBendavid, is the same, btw IE sucks, not a news for web developers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this

```
if (typeof AudioContext != "undefined") {
    context = new AudioContext()
}
```

Comment: That worked. Is it just me who thinks it's plain idiotic that this does not work in IE?

Comment: It works nowhere else either. It's standard behavior that you have to have a variable declared somewhere (either from your environment, from a `var` statement or from a function argument) before referencing it.

Comment: @CherryDT But why does if (window.AudioContext) work then?

Comment: Because the `window` variable is defined. You are checking for a property of the `window` object, which is fine. Try `console.log(abc);`(reference error) and `var x = {}; console.log(x.abc);` (no error, undefined) to see what I mean. It's just a "coincidence" (defined by the browser) that `window` is also the global object here, it's not a feature of the language itself.

Comment: @CherryDT Oh, man I feel stupid. That does make a lot more sense. Is it okay to just check for window.AudioContext in the if statement, then?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen I would strongly recommend to always use typeof instead. It's kind of standard in JavaScript to do that validation.

Comment: Personally I find `if(window.AudioContext)` nicer to read because no string is involved, but I guess it's a matter of taste because it makes no real difference except for the fact that if `AudioContext` is not an object but the number zero (or false or null, ...) the `typeof` will yield true but the other method will yield false. But in this case you are screwed anyway because to prevent things called `AudioContext` which are no real `AudioContext` from sneaking in, you would need to do all kinds of other checks ^^

Comment: @CherryDT In that case, using window.AudioContext works perfectly in my situation.